# ワードプレスで、2番目の投稿から一覧表示させる方法が上手くいきません。

Tags: php, html, wordpress

ワードプレスでサイトを作成しています。
そして、アーカイブページの記事の一覧を作成するに当たり、
ページネーションを作成し、表示記事の１つ目の記事と２つ目の記事の画像の大きさを変えたいと考えています。

なんとか、上記の内容を行うことが出来たのですが、一行目と２行目の記事の内容が、
おなじになってしまいました。

マルチポスト(https://teratail.com/questions/5069i012dnih3u)
(https://qiita.com/keikkkk/questions/6b69fb04bd4d1c85560c)

試したこと
（ 'offset' => 1,を加えるイメージ説明）
上記のコードを打ち込んでも直しません、
また素人のため、細かなPHPのルールを理解出来ていないのが、
理由に気づけ無い原因かもしれません。

PHP

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section class="blog-archive-wrapper">
    <div class="blog-archive-wrapper-second">
        <div class="blog-archive-outer">    
            <h2 class="blog-archive-outer-title">新着一覧</h2>  
   <div>
   <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


    <?php
        $paged = get_query_var('paged')? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $information= new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => 1,
                ));
    ?>
    <ul>    <!-- ループ -->
        <li>

 <?php if ($wp_query->current_post == 0) { ?>                   

 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-item"></a> 
        <div class="blog-item-thumbnail-content">
        <div class="blog-list-wrapper-second"> 
          <?php // アイキャッチを表示させる start ?>    
            <div class="blog-item-thumbnail-second">
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                <div class="thumbnail-image-second"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(240, 148)); ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php // アイキャッチを表示させる end ?>
        </div>  
        <div class="blog-list-category">
         
<?php $cat = $cat[0]; ?>
<p class="blog-list-category-title"><?php echo get_cat_name($cat->term_id); ?></p>
        </div>
              
        <div class="blog-item-content"> 
                 <p class="blog-item-day-second"><?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?></p>
                <?php // タイトルを表示させる start ?>
                <h3 class="blog-item-title">
                <?php echo mb_substr($post->post_title, 0, 30).'……'; ?>
               </h3>
                <?php // タイトルを表示させる end ?>
              <?php // 抜粋を表示させる start ?>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
                <?php // 抜粋を表示させる end ?>     
        </div>
    </div>

  

    <?php } ?>
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'offset' => 1,
    
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

  <div class="blog-list-category">
  <?php $cat = get_the_category(); ?>


<?php $cat = $cat[0]; ?>
<p class="blog-list-category-title"><?php echo get_cat_name($cat->term_id); ?></p>
  </div>
 <div class="blog-list-list-item">
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-item"></a> 

        <div class="blog-item-thumbnail-content-second">
        <div class="blog-list-wrapper"> 
          <?php // アイキャッチを表示させる start ?>    
            <div class="blog-item-thumbnail-second">
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                <div class="thumbnail-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(240, 179)); ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php // アイキャッチを表示させる end ?>
        </div>  
              
        <div class="blog-item-content"> 
                 <p class="blog-item-day-second"><?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?></p>
                <?php // タイトルを表示させる start ?>
                <h3 class="blog-item-title">
                <?php echo mb_substr($post->post_title, 0, 30).'……'; ?>
               </h3>
                <?php // タイトルを表示させる end ?>
              <?php // 抜粋を表示させる start ?>
                <p class="blog-item-read">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
                </p>
                <?php // 抜粋を表示させる end ?>     
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>

 <?php endwhile; ?>
   </div> 
                </li>
               
        </ul>
        <?php
              // サブクエリをリセット
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>

<?php
    if( function_exists('wp_pagenavi') ) {
            wp_pagenavi(array('query' => $information));
     }
?>
<?php endif;?>
</div>

 </div>

     
</section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

一行目と２行目がおなじになっています。

[image]

8, 'offset' => 1, ); $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

も効いていないようで,表示数の合計が１０になりません１１表示されてしまいます。

Comment: ご存知のかた何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: このページでWP_Queryでは、paged と offset を設定すると上手く動かないと書いてあります。（また、回避方法も）　https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination

Comment: 表示件数が違うのは、argsへの指定パラメータが1回目と2回目が違うからでは？

Comment: サイトを教えていただきありがとうございます。argsの１つ目は１回だけ表示して２回目は９回表示する必要があるのです、一番上の記事だけ画像のサイズが違うので、

Comment: 単純に考えると、 while (have_posts())のループ内で、if分で処理を分ければ良いのでは？

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="pagination">
    <div class="list-box">
        <ul>
        <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post_type'      => 'post', // ページの種類（例、page、post、カスタム投稿タイプ）
            'paged'          => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' => 10, // 表示件数
            'orderby'        => 'date',
            'order'          => 'DESC'
        ) );
        if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
            while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
            ?>
                <?php // ブログの一覧を表示する start ?>
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <article class="blog-list__list-item">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-item">
                            <?php // アイキャッチを表示させる start ?>    
                            <div class="blog-item__thumbnail-second">
                                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                                <img class="blog-item__thumbnail-image-second" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('large'); ?>">
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php // アイキャッチを表示させる end ?>
                            <div class="blog-item__content">
                                <?php // タイトルを表示させる start ?>
                                <h3 class="blog-item__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <?php // タイトルを表示させる end ?>
                                <?php // 抜粋を表示させる start ?>
                                <h3 class="blog-item__read"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h3>
                                <?php // 抜粋を表示させる end ?>
                                <div class="blog-item__button">
                                    <span class="blog-item__button-more">記事を読む</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </article>
                    <?php break; ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <article class="blog-list__list-item">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-item">
                            <?php // アイキャッチを表示させる start ?>    
                            <div class="blog-item__thumbnail">
                                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                                <img class="blog-item__thumbnail-image" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('large'); ?>">
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php // アイキャッチを表示させる end ?>
                            <div class="blog-item__content">
                                <?php // タイトルを表示させる start ?>
                                <h3 class="blog-item__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <?php // タイトルを表示させる end ?>
                                <?php // 抜粋を表示させる start ?>
                                <h3 class="blog-item__read"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h3>
                                <?php // 抜粋を表示させる end ?>
                                <div class="blog-item__button">
                                    <span class="blog-item__button-more">記事を読む</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </article>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

                <?php // ブログの一覧を表示する end ?>
                <?php break; ?>
            <?php
            endwhile;
        else:
            echo '<div><p>ありません。</p></div>';
        endif;
        ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

これで出来ました。
一旦位置から違うネットで拾ったコードを使いやり直し、

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- 最初の投稿のレイアウト -->

<!-- 1件表示してbreakでループを抜ける -->
<?php break; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<!-- 2件目からループが始まるはず -->
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- 2件目以降の投稿のレイアウト -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif: ?>
```

このようにすることで出来ました。

```
<?php break; ?>
```

を最後に追加してループを止めることで完成です。
ご協力くださった、皆様ありがとうございました。